# CGIの標準入力のテスト

Tags: linux, c, cgi

CGIアプリをC言語で作っていますが、サーバー側のコンソールでテストデーターを、標準入力から入力してテストすることは出来るのでしょうか？
OS Linux debian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

環境がUNIX系であれば、以下のサイトにあるような方法でテストできるはずです。(ただし、perl -d xxx.cgi部分を cで作成されたCGI名に変更する必要があります。)

- [CGIの古典的デバッグ(GET編)](http://miau.s9.xrea.com/blog/index.php?itemid=689)
- [CGIの古典的デバッグ(POST編)](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/miau/20090828/1251424242)

Answer (score 1):

できますかという質問の答えは Yes/No のどちらかで、この場合 Yes なわけですが

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LINELEN 1024
int main() {
    char buf[LINELEN];
    puts("Content-type: text-plain; charset=iso-8850-1");
    while (fgets(buf, LINELEN, stdin)) {
        puts(buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

サーバー上 `httpd` が cgi プロセスを起動した際の「 cgi プロセス側標準入力」が何であるかは要考察で、多分キーボードではないわけです。そもそも論として、いつクライアントがアクセスしてくるかわからない状況で、応答内容をサーバー上オペレーターがキーボードから入力するというのは運用的にありえないです（たとえデバッグ目的であっても）

本当にやりたい案件は何か再考察することをお勧めします。